# How to create dataset for a sankey diagram?

Tags: r, sankey-diagram

I am doing a class in Data Visualisation and thought that a sankey diagram is quite an interesting visualisation of data. 
I am unsure however, how the dataset should look, respectively how I create a dataset that I can use.

So the question is: what criteria does my dataset need to fulfill to be useable in a sankey diagram?

Comment: Maybe this link helps you: https://plot.ly/r/sankey-diagram/

Comment: More of a theory question. Just because you wnat to use an unnamed and possibly even unknown R package, does not make this a coding question. Perhaps the SE CrossValidated or Data Science forums would consider this on topic. Please read their intro pages before posting this there. I suggest deleting this question.